# corrupt development.ini code

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pyramid

I am working through a python pyramid tutorial, and I have been making as many notes as I can inside the files I am writing.

something strange happened, I'd like to know why.

I wrote the development.ini file like was done in the tutorial then added notes.

```
# we are using this file for configureation in development

# config our wsgi
[app:main]
# which entry point to use as the app
use = egg:mysite
# reloads when templates are changed, not to be used in production
pyramid.reload_templates = true

#which server to use
[server:main]
#get the main entry point from the waitress package
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6534

# this is a great way to remove code for the rest of our package
# more importantly this file is easy to tweak for launching our package in a different manner
```

running **pserve development.ini** chrome returns:

```
This site can’t be reached

0.0.0.0 refused to connect.
Search Google for 6543
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I remove the comments:

```
[app:main]
use = egg:mysite
pyramid.reload_templates = true

[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6534
```

I receive the same error as before.

```
This site can’t be reached

0.0.0.0 refused to connect.
Search Google for 6543
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

THEN I copy and paste code from the tutorials repo into development.ini:

```
[app:main]
use = egg:mysite
pyramid.reload_templates = true

[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6543
```

I am successfully able to reach localhost.

---

I am most interested to know, why this happened, how to avoid this problem, and if possible how to comment a development.ini file.

note:

- I am using PyCharm as my ide
- I am running this code on my local computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` means that the port you entered in Chrome's address bar does not align with the port number configuration in your `.ini` file.  Look very carefully at your port numbers to make sure they align.  You transposed the `4` and `3` in your original `.ini` (`port = 6534`), so I assume you tried to reach http://0.0.0.0:6543 in Chrome's address bar.

Bonus tip: PyCharm allows you to compare a single file's history on disk as well as version control. This helps reveal typographical errors. Right/CTRL-click on the file, *Local History > Show History*.

Comment: wow! that was an awesome tip, totally made this embarrassing question worth it.